# JarSigner done within java?

Tags: java, jar, sign, jarsigner

Is it possible to use the JarSigner class to sign a jar file within java? Currently I am using:

```
String args[] = {"-keystore", keystore, "-storepass", password, jar, keyname};
JarSigner js = new JarSigner();
js.run(args);
```

but if anything fails, the js.run void will call a System.exit(-1) causing my entire application to crash. I was thinking about running that inside of a thread, joining it until it completes, and checking for the return code. Just seeing if there is a more formal way of doing that... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That won't work. `System.exit()` will terminate the entire VM, not just the thread that executes it.

Comment: is there any way to catch a System.exit?

Comment: In principle you could do that by making a custom classloader to load the foreign code, and have it install some bytecode of your own for `java.lang.System`. But that is not for the faint of heart -- you'd need to handle the chaining of all _other_ System methods to the VM's implementations yourself. It's probably much easier and maintainable simply to recreate the jar signing process yourself with java.util.zip.* and java.security.* tools.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Sun/Oracle `JarSigner` included in JDK tools. You have two option:

- Reuse by copy/paste most of the `run` method to skip the `System.exit` in `catch` clause from the [OpenJDK source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/tools/JarSigner.java#JarSigner.run%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) for instance
- Use [JarSigner from GNU ClassPath project](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/gnu/classpath/tools/jarsigner/JarSigner.java.html) which `start` method does not invoke `System.exit` but throws exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you sign only with SHA1withRSA algorithm, there is a project called [zip-signer](http://code.google.com/p/zip-signer/). The main target of this project is Android, but the core library of this project, "zipsigner-lib", doesn't depend on Android system so it works in PC as well. You can take a look at sample code for PC named [zipsigner-cmdline](http://code.google.com/p/zip-signer/source/browse/zipsigner-cmdline/trunk/src/main/java/kellinwood/zipsigner/cmdline/Main.java).

If you need algorithms other than SHA1withRSA, though, you'll probably have to adapt source codes from the GNU ClassPath project, which is no easy task.